# Is there a rule about hyphens in primvar names in Universal Scene Description

Tags: usd

I'm reading a .USDA file (exported by blender) via USD.NET and and when looking at loading texture data I have an image texture defined within a material like this:

```
            def Shader "Image_Texture"
            {
                uniform token info:id = "UsdUVTexture"
                asset inputs:file = @./textures/BodyBase.png@
                token inputs:sourceColorSpace = "sRGB"
                float2 inputs:st.connect = </_materials/Material_001/preview/uvmap.outputs:result>
                float3 outputs:rgb
            }

            def Shader "uvmap"
            {
                uniform token info:id = "UsdPrimvarReader_float2"
                token inputs:varname = "Cube_001-mesh-map-0"
                float2 outputs:result
            }
```

and I read the variable name for st from `uvmap` as "Cube_001-mesh-map-0".
However in the mesh data, I have:

```
texCoord2f[] primvars:Cube_001_mesh_map_0 = [...] (
                interpolation = "faceVarying"
            )
```

i.e. there are no hyphens in the primvar name. Is this a convention that I should be accounting for, as in is it safe to just always convert hyphens to underscores when trying to look up primvars?

The following code won't find the primvar if `parameterPath` uses the hyphenated version:

```
UsdGeomPrimvar? GetPrimvar(UsdPrim meshPrim, string parameterPath)
{
    UsdGeomPrimvarsAPI api = new UsdGeomPrimvarsAPI(meshPrim);
    TfToken testToken = new TfToken(parameterPath);
    UsdGeomPrimvar primVar = api.GetPrimvar(testToken);
    if (primVar.IsDefined())
        return primVar;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it doesn't work also if I had hyphens, I had to modify my variable to work.

It is not written anywhere in the documentation but I assumed we should not add hyphen or any other special character that I found such as : spacing, dot, #, \r, \t, \n, [, ], ~, -, :, + ... and I guess many other more